# How to read images from POST call parameter

Tags: java, restlet

I am looking at consuming an image that has been passed along with a post request as a parameter.

I am unable to understand how to consume this image with java restlet.

I want to use this image and send it for printing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To be very honest , i am unable to start off cause i am not understanding how to use the image sent via post request.

Comment: Are you sending picture's path or you uploading a picture on server?

Comment: is this a multipart-post?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to put in a class extending ServerResource called at the POST of the form:

```
@Post
public Representation upload(Representation entity) throws Exception {
    // 1/ Create a factory for disk-based file items
    DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

    // 2/ Create a new file upload handler based on the Restlet
    // FileUpload extension that will parse Restlet requests and
    // generates FileItems.
    RestletFileUpload upload = new RestletFileUpload(factory);

    // 3/ Request is parsed by the handler which generates a
    // list of FileItems
    List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRepresentation(entity);
    String filename = "myImage.png";

    File file = new File(filename);
    for (FileItem fi : items) {
        if (fi.getFieldName().equals("datafile")) {
            System.out.println("Save image ... " + filename);
            fi.write(file);
        }
    }
    // Print your image
    ...
}
```